# Stepping through a Python object list's __doc__s

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can print the first line of the `__doc__` for an object like this:

```
print pexpect.codecs.__doc__.split('\n')[0]
```

However when step through the entire dictionary like this:

```
for member in dir(pexpect):
    print member.__doc__.split('\n')[0]
```

All it returns is a series of:

```
str(object='') -> string
```

How can I get it to return the string as it does in the individual example above?

Comment: ...do you have a question? Perhaps you should try `print type(member)` first...

Comment: `member` is the **name** of the attribute as a stirng, not the string itself. Thus you end up printing the documentation for the `str` class. Use `getattr` to obtain the corresponding attribute value and get the `__doc__` of that.

Comment: @Bakuriu I see what your saying, let me experiment with that.